# C++ vector<pair<int,int>> std::all_of() function problem (redirects to header file)

Tags: c++

I want to check is every pair inside a vector "fully even".

"Fully even" pair is a pair in which first and second elements are both even.

If every pair in vector is "fully even", program should print "Yes".

So, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool func(auto ip) {
if(ip.first%2==0 and ip.second%2==0) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
int main() {
vector<pair<int, int>> vec;
vec.push_back(make_pair(2,2));
vec.push_back(make_pair(2,3));
vec.push_back(make_pair(4,1));
vec.push_back(make_pair(8,3));
vec.push_back(make_pair(7,9));
if(all_of(vec.begin(),vec.end(), [] (auto i) {func(i);}) {
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

"Error: void value not ignored as it ought to be" is what I get when I run this program.

So, any help ? and function "func" must be used, not "return i.first%2==0 and i.second%2==0".

Comment: What's the problem you are seeing, and what have you tried to debug the issue?

Comment: So, what is your problem? Does your code not compile? If so, copy-paste the error message, into your question.

Comment: Typo? Did you mean `[] (auto i) {return func(i);}`, instead of `[] (auto i) {func(i);}`? Or, alternatively, just `all_of(vec.begin(),vec.end(), func)`?

Comment: That "return" was the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

While I was waiting for the answer, I found where the error was:

In the line:
if(all_of(vec.begin(),vec.end(), [] (auto i) {func(i);})) {

I needed to say:

if(all_of(vec.begin(),vec.end(), [] (auto i) {**RETURN** func(i);}))

That's it. :)